# Plotting a constant function with pyplot only works when adding and subtracting the same value. Why?

Tags: python, function, matplotlib

I've been playing around with pyplot and some things are just weird.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def f(x):
    return x**2


def g(x):
    return 5


def h(x):
    return 5+x-x


x = np.linspace(-3.0, 3.0, num=50)
plt.plot(x, f(x)) #works
plt.plot(x, g(x)) #crashes
plt.plot(x, h(x)) #works
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

f(x) works as expected. g(x) crashes and to draw a line I have to use the workaround in h(x). Why is that? All of these functions only return numbers but one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: Define `crashes` - show the complete exception traceback, formatted the same way as the code.

Comment: Change the return statement like `def g(x):
    return x - 5`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x` is a `numpy` array of size 50. `f(x)` and `h(x)` both return arrays of the same size. So you can plot one against the other.

`g(x)` returns the scalar 5, which has the size 1. And you cannot plot an array of size 50 against something with size 1.

You can modify it like so:

```py
def g(x):
    return np.ones_like(x)*5
```

This returns an array of the same size (and shape) as the input array, so you can plot the input against the output.

Comment: Ok now I understand why g(x) doenst work, but I still dont get why f(x) and h(x) do work?

Comment: This is what makes `numpy` so powerful: vectorized operations. Your functions `f()` and `h()` do not know anything about `x` until you call them, but when you do, you call them with the `numpy` array `x`, so `numpy` rules apply. In `numpy`: `array + scalar = each element in array + scalar`. You call this addition (could also be multiplication, exponentiation, triginometric functions, etc.) once, and `numpy` computes the function for each element without any loops (in a *vectorized* manner). Reading: [1](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html)

Comment: More reading: [2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html), [3](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html). That's as much that I can explain in a comment. But it is a really powerful idea, so go explore it! It is essential for making most use out of `numpy`. Hope it helps.